# Magento 2 Rewrite minicart default.html with phtml

Tags: magento2, layout, mini-cart

I have created a file `app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` to write the Magento 2 standard mini cart default.html. And this is working fine.

However, I need to add some ***PHP code*** into my ***default.html***. Can I change this to **default.phtml**, so I can add PHP code? and how do I tell the system to use **default.phtml** as the mini cart template? I can't find a layout.xml where we can define the file name.

Comment: it's loading by knkout UiComponent so you can not change it from `.html` to `.phtml`

Comment: you can add any thing php code inside Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem with in function GetItemData and call them inside default.html file

Comment: how do you add new things to the function @AnsarHusain can you show me a example i used a preferenace to add a new value in and when ever i call that to html Unable to process binding "html: function(){return row_total }"
Message: row_total is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2 using [private content](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) and KnockoutJs for load minicart.

- [Layout config](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L17)
- [Component Js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js)
- [Template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html)
- [Item template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html)

Example add price row total to minicart.

Override DefaultItem customer data Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Your_Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem"/>
```

Add row total to doGetItemData function

```
protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
            'row_total' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getRowTotal()),
        ];
    }
```

Display on default template. Add snippet code below to default template (app/design/frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html)

```
<div class="row-total" data-bind="html: row_total"></div>
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Hi I am new with Knockout js, i have question if i pass 'row_total' => '1' can i do a check in the html by <! -- ko if: row_total -- > show h1 title and close if off by < !-- /ko -- > would this work?

Comment: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return row_total }"
Message: row_total is not defined also i get this when i do your method

Comment: Did you add row_total to doGetItemData?

Comment: @ bang.nguyen47, it wont work because its protected even if you use preference it wouldn't work. while i was reading you could use a plugin on \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem::getItemData()

Comment: Hi @jibingeorge in magento 2 we can override protected function by preference. show me your code?

Comment: Hi, you are right but this is the information i have found. 
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/904/2 - 
You should not “override” a standard class in Magento 2, because you will break all the other poor-written extensions, which try to “override” the same class too.
As you can see, the \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem::doGetItemData() 83 is called only from the public \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem::getItemData() 131 method, and you can use an after-plugin for it and modify its result.
Now it works what i expected to do

Comment: @jibingeorge thank for your information