# file not created in pub/static

Tags: magento2, template

I have copied the file located in: `vendor/magento/module_checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

to my theme dir:`app/design/frontend/MyVendor/Mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

After clearing the `cache` and generating `static-content`, the template doesn't render and the file does not appear in `pub static` folder.
Is the path wrong? Is there a command i need to run?

I found this question, where the path was correct:
[Magento 2 Rewrite minicart default.html with phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239724/magento-2-rewrite-minicart-default-html-with-phtml)

Comment: delete the content manually from `pub/static/frontend` and then run the `static-deploy -f` command

Comment: worked! ty @Chikku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the content manually from `pub/static/frontend` and then run the `static-deploy -f` command